# LINQ Expression Tree Parsing Issue

Tags: linq, lambda, expression

I am developing a simple class that maps any Tuples from database, by convention, to CLR objects.

Here in my work, i cannot use EntityFramework, because database is giant and we have splitted models and is impossible to cross different contexts.

So i started develop my own ORM mapper, that generate insert, update and delete commands.
i am trying to develop the select method, that generates select CMD.

This method receives a `Expression<T, bool>` filter by parameter that i want to filter the data.

One thing that i really want to use is something like:

```
int value = 1;
int valu2 = 40;

mapper.Select<MyEntity>(m => m.id> value && m.id<= value2);
```

The big problem is that `filter.body.toString()` generates a string as is, and, what i really want to do is to replace the values of "value" and "value2" by their values declared on their variables...

Someone can give me a light?

Really Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I parsed the expr tree in a simple manner, just to build the filter.

Here's how i did it.

```
private static String ParseFilter(Expression expr)
    {
        return ParseFilter(expr, new ExpressionUtilFilterClass()).data.ToString();
    }

    // Recursive algorithm
    private
    static
    ExpressionUtilFilterClass                            // Return type
    ParseFilter(
        Expression expr,
        ExpressionUtilFilterClass info          // Used to pass information in recursive manner
    )
    {

        Type exprType = expr.GetType();

        if ( exprType != typeof(BinaryExpression) && exprType != typeof(MemberExpression) && exprType != typeof(ConstantExpression) )
            throw new InvalidOperationException("unsupported filter");


        if ( exprType == typeof(BinaryExpression) )
        {
            //
            // We have 2 expressions (left and right)
            // 

            BinaryExpression bExpr = (BinaryExpression)expr;
            ExpressionUtilFilterClass recursion;

            StringBuilder subOperation = new StringBuilder();
            recursion = ParseFilter(bExpr.Left, info);              // Go left in depth - we don't know the type yet

            subOperation.Append("( ");
            subOperation.Append(recursion.data);
            subOperation.Append(" ");

            subOperation.Append(_expressionOperator[bExpr.NodeType]);
            subOperation.Append(" ");

            recursion = ParseFilter(bExpr.Right, recursion);               // Pass reference that contains type information!

            subOperation.Append(recursion.data);
            subOperation.Append(" )");

            // Affect data subpart and pass to upper caller
            recursion.data = subOperation.ToString();

            return recursion;
        }

        else
        {
            MemberExpression mExpr;
            ParameterExpression pExpr;
            ConstantExpression cExpr;

            //
            // We need distinct if we are accessing to capturated variables (need map to sql) or constant variables
            //

            if ( ( mExpr = expr as MemberExpression ) != null )
            {
                if ( ( pExpr = ( mExpr.Expression as ParameterExpression ) ) != null )
                {
                    info.parameterType = mExpr.Expression.Type;        // Type of parameter (must be untouched)
                    info.data = GetMappingForProperty(info.parameterType, mExpr.Member.Name);                     // Must have a map to SQL (criar metodo que faz mapeamento)!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

                    return info;
                }
                else
                {
                    cExpr = (ConstantExpression)mExpr.Expression;

                    object obj = cExpr.Value;               // Get anonymous object
                    string objField = mExpr.Member.Name;

                    FieldInfo value = obj.GetType().GetField(objField);  // Read native value
                    string nativeData = value.GetValue(obj).ToString();

                    info.data = nativeData;
                    return info;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cExpr = (ConstantExpression)expr;
                string nativeData = cExpr.Value.ToString();

                info.data = nativeData;
                return info;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way to achieve this. You will have to parse the entire syntax tree in a recursive manner and convert it to a where clause, which looks like this:

`WHERE id > 1 AND id < 40`

See a blog on [Expression Tree Basics](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx). It is not the full answer to your question; however, it may give you a starting point.